# do not allow user to navigate away from page if text box contains text

Tags: javascript

I am using this JS Code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Any changes you have made WILL be lost!";
}
```

to display an alert window if the user tries to navigate away from the page

i only want the alert to display if there is text in a text area

i have tried:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var update_text = document.getElementById('ticket_update').value; 
    if(!update_text == '') {
        return "Any changes you have made WILL be lost!";
    }
}
```

but it doesn't display the alert at all if the text area is empty or not

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine for me, but why ask to save changes if there is no value, shouldn't it be if there actually is something else than an empty string (as in `!= ''`), then ask to save ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NGFfn/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pbSGw/ - Works in chrome

Comment: see my edit, missed out the !

Comment: ok well that's your problem, you're negating the update text then asking if it equals "".  That's never going to happen.  Needs to be !=

Comment: @adeneo your code is alerting me even if the box is blank

Comment: @numbers1311407 your fiddle is doing the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
if(!update_text == '')
```

With order of operations, your code looks like

```
if( (!update_text) == '')
```

So when there is a value it is empty `!("")` is true so your check is `true == ''`

It needs to be

```
if(update_text !== '')
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxg49/1/)

or

```
if(update_text.length)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxg49/)

Comment: With your order of operations example, wouldn't `if( !(update_text == '') );` also be correct?

Comment: this is always displaying the alert if the update_text is blank or not

Comment: IS the value empty or does it have empty whitespace in it? If it has whitespace, you would have to trim it. AH, if you were using the length one, you do not need the `!`, that was a typo.

Comment: still the same thing - my textarea looks like <textarea name="ticket_update" id="ticket_update" style="width:100%; height:160px;"></textarea> and  it is in a PHP variable which i echo lower down the page to display the text area

Comment: `console.log("Value:",escape(update_text)); console.log("Length:",update_text.length);` displays what?

Comment: this isn't displaying anything

Comment: Did you hit cancel and look at the console?